# How to use returning clause on update/upsert

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlboiler

I wish to know how I can use postgres `returning` clause with SQL Boiler elegantly.

For example I wish to update some object by some fields and return the object id:

```
 err = queries.RawG(`update users
                     set name='test-name'
                     WHERE email='test@example.com'
                     RETURNING id`).Bind(ctx, boil.GetDB(), &user)
```

The following is working as expected, the user column has been updated and I got back the user id, but I'm looking for more elegant ways to do the same without using `queries.RawG`